# Какой класс использовать для нумерованного списка?

Tags: java

Как создать список, где все объекты имеют свой порядковый номер (который присваивается в момент их создания и никогда не меняется)

Нужно чтобы можно было добавить объект либо в первое из пустых полей, либо в его конец (пустые поля должны остаться после того, как я удалю из него некоторые объекты)

Comment: Если объект удалили, то связанный с ним номер переиспользуется?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, какую *коллекцию* вам использовать?

Comment: Что значит _можно было добавить объект либо в первое из пустых полей_?  Вы имеете в виду переиспользовать идентификатор объекта после удаления?

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что Вам подойдет `LinkedHashMap`, в качестве ключа Вы можете хранить этот самый уникальный номер, в качестве значения - объект. При удалении устанавливать значение `null` для ключа удаляемого объекта, а при добавлении за O(n) находить первый `null` и вставлять туда объект либо, если не найден, вставлять с его ключом